# Winston not logging events in productions version of a Node.js app hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, logging, google-compute-engine, winston

I am using winston to log some events in my app. When I run my code with `node app.js` locally, winston logs the events just fine. But when I push my code to the server (`gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml`), or even run it in production environment locally (`gcloud preview app run app.yaml`) it doesn't log any event. Locally winston creates the `general.log` and `request.log` and edits them as required, but it doesn't do any of that in production mode.

Here is my logging.js code

```
"use strict";

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var winston = require('winston');
var expressWinston = require('express-winston');


module.exports = function(logPath) {

  // Create logging directory if necessary.
  if (!fs.existsSync(logPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logPath);
  }


  /*
    Logger to capture all requests and output them to the console
    as well as request.log.
  */
  // [START requests]
  var requestLogger = expressWinston.logger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({
        json: false
      }),
      new winston.transports.File({
        filename: path.join(logPath, 'request.log'),
      })
    ],
    expressFormat: true
  });
  // [END requests]


  /*
    Logger to capture any top-level errors from requests and
    output them in error.log
  */
  // [START errors]
  var errorLogger = expressWinston.errorLogger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({
        json: false
      }),
      new winston.transports.File({
        filename: path.join(logPath, 'error.log'),
      })
    ]
  });
  // [END errors]


  /*
    General logger used for .log, .info, etc. Outputs all logs
    to the console as well as general.log.
  */
  // [START general]
  winston.add(winston.transports.File, {
    filename: path.join(logPath, 'general.log')
  });
  // [END general]


  return {
    requestLogger: requestLogger,
    errorLogger: errorLogger,
    error: winston.error,
    warn: winston.warn,
    info: winston.info,
    log: winston.log,
    verbose: winston.verbose,
    debug: winston.debug,
    silly: winston.silly
  };

};
```

Here is a sample (unimportant) event I am logging for testing purposes in app.js

```
var logging = require('./lib/logging')(process.env.LOG_PATH || './');
app.use(logging.requestLogger);
app.use(logging.errorLogger);
logging.info("Sample test log");
```

Why isn't this code working in production mode?

P.S I followed the steps here to set up this code

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/logging-application-events

Answer (score 1):

Your NodeJS is actually running in a Docker container on a Managed VM from Google Compute Engine.

You have to SSH to your managed VM and connect to the container.

```
sudo docker ps
```

[image: sudo docker ps]

This should output 4 containers :
**gunicorn** and **nginx** are for the proxy, **fluentd** is the connector to log to App Engine and finally **npm start** is your Node app

```
sudo docker exec -it <ID of the container running npm start> bash
```

This gives you the prompt on the container, you should be able to see the log files from there.

---

Note that if you want to see your logs on the App Engine Web console (you should place those files in the folder '**/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/*.log**'

[image: App Engin web console]

Comment: Thanks! I SSH'ed into my instance and tried navigating to the custom_logs directory. But the path was like this : '/var/log/app_engine/app/custom_logs/*.log' and when I run it with that path the app breaks and when I run it with the path you gave nothing happens and yes I want to see my logs in the Web Console.

Comment: The folder 'custom_logs' doesn't exist by default, but I think you create it when you call your logger. What is the logPath you provide ? It should be _'/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/'_

Answer (score 0):

It is really not easy to create and view logs in google cloud while I am writing this. 
I want to suggest you an alternative of logging when using google cloud. you might want to try using winston with papertrail.

You can use `winston-express` and `winston-papertrail` node modules for logging your requests. Papertrail provides nice colorful UI to analyze your logs quickly.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173862/842386 for details about how you can configure.